# How to put a variable inside a html String, in c# codeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, code-behind

[image]

The idea is put the variable name inside the html string.

```
 string name = "mario";
```

```
 var html = @"<table style=""height: 171px; margin - left: auto; margin - right: auto;"" border=""1"" width=""676"">
                           <tbody><tr><td style=""width: 225px;"">name</td>
                           <td style=""width: 225px;"">2</td> <td style=""width: 225px;"">3</td></tr><tr>
                           <td style=""width: 225px;"">4</td> <td style=""width: 225px;"">5</td> <td style=""width: 225px;"">6</td></tr>
                            </tbody></table>";
```

Comment: just use a template - i would suggest putting this in a control

Comment: `html` is just a string so you can insert the variable using normal C# interpolation:  `var html = $"<table style=.....{name}....</table>"`

Comment: You can combine `$` (interpolated string) and `@` (verbatim string), so you can say `var html = $@"<table style=.....{name}....</table>"`

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest way is:

```
 string name = "mario";
     var html = @"<table style=""height: 171px; margin - left: auto; margin - right: auto;"" border=""1"" width=""676"">
                       <tbody><tr><td style=""width: 225px;"">"+name+@"</td>
                       <td style=""width: 225px;"">2</td> <td style=""width: 225px;"">3</td></tr><tr>
                       <td style=""width: 225px;"">4</td> <td style=""width: 225px;"">5</td> <td style=""width: 225px;"">6</td></tr>
                        </tbody></table>";

    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(html));
```

and the Newest way is:

```
     string name = "mario";
     var html = $@"<table style=""height: 171px; margin - left: auto; margin - right: auto;"" border=""1"" width=""676"">
                       <tbody><tr><td style=""width: 225px;"">{name}</td>
                       <td style=""width: 225px;"">2</td> <td style=""width: 225px;"">3</td></tr><tr>
                       <td style=""width: 225px;"">4</td> <td style=""width: 225px;"">5</td> <td style=""width: 225px;"">6</td></tr>
                        </tbody></table>";
    
    Console.WriteLine(html);a
```